# Flutter HTTP request asynchronous suspension to maps.googleapis.com

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, async-await

I am a beginner at learning Flutter and Dart. I am trying to get my location initially with `$lat` and `$lng` variables and display it via static google map using an HTTP request but upon clicking the `TextButton` widget, the application hangs. It displays an async suspension happens but did not specify what line.

This is my location_input.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:favorite_places/models/place.dart';

class LocationInput extends StatefulWidget {
  const LocationInput({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LocationInputState();
  }
}

class _LocationInputState extends State<LocationInput> {
  PlaceLocation? _pickedLocation;
  var _isGettingLocation = false;

  String get locationImage {
    if (_pickedLocation == null) {
      return '';
    }
    final lat = _pickedLocation!.latitude;
    final lng = _pickedLocation!.longitude;

    return 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=$lat,$lng&zoom=16&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:A%7C$lat,$lng&key=API_KEY';
  }

  void _getCurrentLocation() async {
    Location location = Location();

    bool serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus permissionGranted;
    LocationData locationData;

    serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      _isGettingLocation = true;
    });

    locationData = await location.getLocation();
    final lat = locationData.latitude;
    final lng = locationData.longitude;

    if (lat == null || lng == null) {
      return;
    }

    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$lng&key=API_KEY');

    final response = await http.get(url);
    final resData = json.decode(response.body);
    final address = resData['results'][0]['formatted_address'];

    setState(() {
      _pickedLocation = PlaceLocation(
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: lng,
        address: address,
      );
      _isGettingLocation = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget previewContent = Text(
      'No Location Chosen',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: Theme.of(context)
          .textTheme
          .bodyLarge!
          .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
    );

    if (_pickedLocation != null) {
      previewContent = Image.network(
        locationImage,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
      );
    }
    if (_isGettingLocation) {
      previewContent = const CircularProgressIndicator();
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 170,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
            width: 1,
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.2),
          )),
          child: previewContent,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: _getCurrentLocation,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.location_on),
              label: const Text('Get Location'),
            ),
            TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.map),
              label: const Text('Get Map'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I already tested both HTTP url with static latitude and longitude value and both works as expected. The problem really lies within the async-await.

Answer (score 2):

1. Debugging would help here though.
2. You're requesting location without specifying accuracy and interval (chaneSettings method), maybe this is the issue.
3. Make sure you've added permisssions in AndroidMainfest and/or Info.plist files.
4. If that's emulator you're testing on, change location manually/set route in the emulator's settings.
   Hope one of these might help

Comment: Hi, as far as item 3 is concern, according to the updated documentation, https://pub.dev/packages/location, no additional lines should be added for the android manifest file.

Comment: I tested it on a real android device and seems to work there just fine. I managed to display the snippet of a map. So it is the emulator that is having a problem.

Comment: I've removed the API key from the post for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Location package by [Geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator):

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

/// Determine the current position of the device.

Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;

  // Test if location services are enabled.
  serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    // Location services are not enabled
    return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
  }

  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      // Permissions are denied
      return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
    }
  }     
  return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
}
```

Use this method to fetch the device current location; then you can take the latitude and longitude.

just follow carefull the steps to install it

Comment: Hi, I atleast get the initial lat and lang when using Location package and wanted to stay with there instead of Geolocator. The problem lies when I try to convert that values into a human readable location and display it in a snippet of a map (gmap for this instance). So I do not think this would solve what my issue is. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that my emulator is not receiving internet connection. So a simple cold boot did the job.